# Problem Inserting password into sql server db

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, insert

I'm trying to insert password into sql server db. The password is already like this `0x29E59C9B1ABD5F2DF024CCAC61FBDDDD` from the function that encrypts it. The column data type is binary(16), but when I execute the query, it returns

> Implicit conversion from data type varchar to binary is not allowed.
>   Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Tried using `Convert(binary(16))`, but I'm getting the same error. Any ideas? All this in PHP

This function encrypts my passwords

```
enter code here

    function encrypt($str) {
$key = array();
$dst = array();
$i = 0;

$nBytes = strlen($str);
        while ($i < $nBytes){
             $i++;
                $key[$i] = ord(substr($str, $i - 1, 1));
                $dst[$i] = $key[$i];
}  

$rslt = $key[1] + $key[2]*256 + $key[3]*65536 + $key[4]*16777216;
$one = $rslt * 213119 + 2529077;
$one = $one - intval($one/ 4294967296) * 4294967296;

$rslt = $key[5] + $key[6]*256 + $key[7]*65536 + $key[8]*16777216;
$two = $rslt * 213247 + 2529089;
$two = $two - intval($two/ 4294967296) * 4294967296;

$rslt = $key[9] + $key[10]*256 + $key[11]*65536 + $key[12]*16777216;
$three = $rslt * 213203 + 2529589;
$three = $three - intval($three/ 4294967296) * 4294967296;

$rslt = $key[13] + $key[14]*256 + $key[15]*65536 + $key[16]*16777216;
$four = $rslt * 213821 + 2529997;
$four = $four - intval($four/ 4294967296) * 4294967296;

$key[4] = intval($one/16777216);        
$key[3] = intval(($one - $key[4] * 16777216) / 65535);
$key[2] = intval(($one - $key[4] * 16777216 - $key[3] * 65536) / 256);
$key[1] = intval(($one - $key[4] * 16777216 - $key[3] * 65536 - $key[2] * 256));

$key[8] = intval($two/16777216);     
$key[7] = intval(($two - $key[8] * 16777216) / 65535);
$key[6] = intval(($two - $key[8] * 16777216 - $key[7] * 65536) / 256);
$key[5] = intval(($two - $key[8] * 16777216 - $key[7] * 65536 - $key[6] * 256));

$key[12] = intval($three/16777216);     
$key[11] = intval(($three - $key[12] * 16777216) / 65535);
$key[10] = intval(($three - $key[12] * 16777216 - $key[11] * 65536) / 256);
$key[9] = intval(($three - $key[12] * 16777216 - $key[11] * 65536 - $key[10] * 256));

$key[16] = intval($four/16777216);     
$key[15] = intval(($four - $key[16] * 16777216) / 65535);
$key[14] = intval(($four - $key[16] * 16777216 - $key[15] * 65536) / 256);
$key[13] = intval(($four - $key[16] * 16777216 - $key[15] * 65536 - $key[14] * 256));

$dst[1] = $dst[1] ^ $key[1];

$i=1;
while ($i<16){
    $i++;
    $dst[$i] = $dst[$i] ^ $dst[$i-1] ^ $key[$i];
}

$i=0;
while ($i<16){
    $i++;
    if ($dst[$i] == 0) {
        $dst[$i] = 102;
    }
}

$encrypt = "0x";
$i=0;
while ($i<16){
    $i++;
    if ($dst[$i] < 16) {
        $encrypt = $encrypt . "0" . dechex($dst[$i]);
    } else {
        $encrypt = $encrypt . dechex($dst[$i]);
    }
}
return $encrypt; }
```

Here is the insert to db(codeigniter)

```
public function register_user_account($data4) {
        $db2= $this->load->database('mssqlsrv',TRUE);
        $db2->insert("user_account", $data4);
        $db2->close();
}
```

That's how i pass the data from the form to the controller in order to submit

```
$this->Game_Account_Model->register_user_auth([
                                    "account" => $acc_name,
                                    "password" => encrypt($pass),
                "something" => '_',
                "something2" => '_',
                                    "something1" => encrypt($pass),
                                    "something" => encrypt($pass)
                ]
     );
```

Comment: Post your code here.

Comment: looks like it tries to send it as varchar but data type in db is binary?

Comment: not really on topic, but you should seriously consider not encrypting passwords.. securely hash them instead. Encryption is reversible, hashing is not.

Comment: i know, but this is how the 3rd party app works, and passwords have to be stored this way.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending VARCHAR to SQL, where column is set to binary, things that you can do are:

1. Set SQL column to VARCHAR and it will work.
2. Use base_convert() function to convert string into binary. Ref:https://www.php.net/base_convert

**Converting binary to readable string:**

You can use unpack() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php

**Converting string to binary**

You can check also pack() -
http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php

Comment: 1. Column's data type can't be changed because a program reads from there. Do you think that CAST might work?

Comment: Have you tried base_convert()? Are you getting any errors, if yes, what are they? And typecast definitely won't work in this case, because there are alphabetical chars in the string. Wheres if they were only numbers,it could work, even if typecasting doesn't do the work, decbin() function would work, if the string contains only numbers.

Comment: how can i possibly use base_convert. could you please give me an example? Also i tried to change the data type of the column to varchar, but from the application that reads this info failed to log in. It has to be set as binary

Comment: Maybe I can send the data required to a stored procedure and let it do the insert?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/QaMqYktM There is a tut, how to use base_convert();